# Difference between owner and schema in the database

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

Which the owner of difference in a database schema?
Listen in technical meetings the database staff use the word onwer.

Comment: I dont understand your question. Your text is very different to your title

Comment: Are you talking about SQL Server or Oracle?  You've tagged this for both but those two engines use the terms very differently.  A SQL Server database is rather similar to an Oracle schema (though they are far from exact analogs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Owner is related to permisions over database objects. 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905208(v=sql.80).aspx

Schema is just a way to organize your object inside the db, think like folder for your files.

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/understanding-the-difference-between-owners-and-schemas-in-sql-server